# augeas: insert directive after comment in httpd.conf

Tags: augeas

I'm trying to insert a ServerName directive after the corresponding comment in httpd.conf:

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

This fails:

```
defvar sncomment /files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf/#comment[.= 'ServerName  www.example.com:80']
ins directive after $sncomment
defvar snentry /files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf/directive[preceding-sibling::*[1][$sncomment]]
set $snentry 'ServerName'
set $snentry/arg 'www.domain:80'
```

$sncomment matches the correct line and a blank directive is inserted at the correct point in the tree but $snentry matches every directive in the tree not just the one inserted.  How can I match only the inserted directive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way to match the just inserted directive:

```
defvar snentry /files/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf/directive[. = '']
```

That will work as long there are no other blank directives in the tree.  However, I'd still like to get the preceding-sibling syntax correct if anyone can spot the error in my code.